# Spring-Security : JSP tag isAnonymous() not working after version upagrade

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which we are using Spring-Security for authentication, authorization. After recent upgrade of Spring-security to 4.0.1.RELEASE, there were some issues, but I was able to fix them by changing some stuff in the project. Now, the problem is the JSP tags I am using below is not working :

```
 <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    <div class="registerNow btn btn-info btn-lg btn-regBut">      
    <spring:message code="index.promo.list.item5"/></div>
</sec:authorize>
```

But If I replace the above with hasRole('ROLE_USER'), then it works, but if the user is already logged in, it does not make any sense to show the registration button. So why is that even if the IDE is suggesting the isAnonymous() it does not work, and what parameter should I pass to access, so that non-authenticated users only will see that button. Thanks a lot. :-)

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/dashboard" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/denied" />
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <!--     <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/> -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll" />
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>

        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work*? How?

Comment: @Aleksandr M the button inside it is not shown even if i am logged in or not.

Comment: Have you somehow disabled default anonymous token?

Comment: I dont have any token...shud i paste xml?

Comment: Post it. Also see what `<sec:authentication property="principal" />` shows for **not** authenticating user.

Comment: Different tag `authentication` not `authorize`. ;)

Comment: @AleksandrM : I checked in firebug, it is printing anonymousUser. If that helps, kindly let me know. Thanks.